# "times 510-($-$$) db 0" does not work

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, osdev, x86-16

I am learning about boot sectors. I downloaded nasm-installer-x64.exe from the *NASM* website. My operating system is win7-64bit. When I run the following code it does not work correctly

```
mov ah, 0x0e;

mov al, the_secret;
int 0x10;

mov al, [the_secret];
int 0x10;

mov bx, [the_secret];
add bx, 0x7c00;
mov al, [bx];
int 0x10;

mov al, [0x7c1e];
int 0x10;

jmp $;

the_secret:;
    db 'X';

times 510-($-$$) db 0;
dw 0xaa55;
```

Comment: What makes you think `times 510-($-$$) db 0` does not work? Seems fine to me. Maybe you have some other issue with your bootloader?

Comment: Thank you very much. The image file generated from my asm codes is not correct. Firstly, it contains 526 bytes which is supposed to be 512 bytes. Secondly, it ends up with 0x5500 which should be 0x55aa. I don't know why this happens...

Comment: I found that, the phenomena I described above is caused by the difference between the result compiled by nasm and the result writed into my image file. I use a command `nasm -f bin boot_sect.asm -o boot_sect.bin`, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. If you look at the bottom of my answer I gave an example of how to assemble it, and that matches what I suggested. What commands do you use to put the bootsector on the disk?

Comment: if you don't have the _DD_ command available, I recommend it as a useful tool you can get for Windows that can be used to build disk images. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.zip

Comment: Are you somehow using the windows `copy` command to add files together to produce your disk image?

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't produce an image file. What I said above, "the image file", is actually the file `boot_sect.bin`. A CPU emulator, here I use `bochs`, will load the BIN file to verify my assembly codes.

Comment: I also noticed that, my codes work well after I put your codes from `xor ax,ax` to `cld` to the front of my codes. I think I must read your [General Bootloader Tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076) carefully to deepen my understanding on bootloader. I am just interested in this scope recently. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything wrong with `times 510-($-$$) db 0`. It seems to me your are attempting to find the proper way to access the variable `the_secret` and then display it to the screen. I'll provide one mechanism based on this attempt which has the most promise:

```
mov al, [the_secret];
int 0x10;
```

If you set up *DS* properly, set an origin point using `org 0x7c00` and make sure *BH* is set to the page number you want to write to (you want 0) then the following code should work:

```
[bits 16]          ; 16-Bit code
[org 0x7c00]       ; Set the origin point to 0x7c00

start:
    xor ax,ax      ; We want a segment of 0 for DS for this question
    mov ds,ax      ;     Set AX to appropriate segment value for your situation
    mov es,ax      ; In this case we'll default to ES=DS
    mov bx,0x8000  ; Stack segment can be any usable memory

    mov ss,bx      ; This places it with the top of the stack @ 0x80000.
    mov sp,ax      ; Set SP=0 so the bottom of stack will be @ 0x8FFFF

    cld            ; Set the direction flag to be positive direction

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [the_secret]  ; al = character from memory DS:[the_secret]
    xor bh, bh            ; bh = 0 = video page number
    int 0x10;

    jmp $

the_secret:;
    db 'X';

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

The start up code sets *DS* to zero since we set an origin point of 0x7c00. The bootloader is loaded at 0x0000:0x7c00 (physical address 0x07c00). This ensures accessing the variable `the_secret` will be done properly. `mov al, [the_secret]` is the equivalent of saying `mov al, ds:[the_secret]`. If the *DS* segment register is not set properly, and the origin point isn't set properly, the memory access will not read from the proper location.

[INT 0x10/AH=0x0E](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) requires a page number to be set. The first video display page is 0, *BH* should be set accordingly.

More on the other setup instructions can be found in my StackOverflow answer that contains [General Bootloader Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942).

The code I have presented should display `X` to the console if properly written to a disk image.

---

To assemble this code and produce a disk image (in my example a 720k floppy):

```
nasm -f bin bootload.asm -o bootload.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=720
dd if=bootload.bin of=disk.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

The first command does the assembling of `bootload.asm` into a flat binary file called `bootload.bin`. The second command produces a zero filled disk image (`disk.img`) of size 1024 * 720 (720kb floppy), and the last command copies 512 bytes of data from `bootload.bin` to the first sector of the disk image. `conv=notrunc` tells *DD* not to truncate the file after writing. If you were to leave that off `disk.img` would be 512 bytes long after the bootsector was written.

Comment: Thank you for you elaborate explanation. It helps me a lot, really.

Comment: I recently run "kernel" successfully. After I went through it, I understood more about this code. Today, I find that you mentioned `bh` is needed to be set since it involves the page number. But, I actually did not set it at all. Could you explain more about it for me? What is page number……

Comment: My answer provides a link to information for *Int 10h/ah=0eh*: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm . Ralf Brown's interrupts lists has become a standard for BIOS/DOS information. At the link you should notice it says  `BH = page number` . You can potentially have more than one page of video memory to display to. Page 0 is the default when a system boots. It is a good idea to set BH to zero for this _INT_ call to make sure you write to the default page. Failure to do this may result in the text not appearing. There are a limited number of pages, and possible _BH_ wasn't valid so defaults to 0

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

You can try just replacing the hex of the code snippet.
It should be caused by the new hex corrupting the MBR format