# ASM error in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, osdev

I am having an issue with this piece of code:

```
loop :              

    jmp loop        

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0              
dw 0 xaa55
```

It is giving me an error saying:

> boot.asm:6: error: comma expected after operand 1

I don't know what is causing this. I just started trying os developing, so don't expect me to know that much.

Comment: Have you tried adding a comma after operand 1 on line 6?

Comment: Where do I put the comma?

Comment: Actually that may not be the real problem. It's best to way for someone who knows more. My apologies.

Comment: Remove the space between `0` and `x` . What you want is `dw 0xaa55` . `0x` prefix means the `aa55` is seen as hexadecimal. You want 0xaa55 as the last word in the boot sector as it represents a boot signature that most BIOSes will check for.

Comment: There are more redundant spaces there, like "`loop :`" - is this instruction `loop` with argument `:`, or is this label `loop` (and the colon is used to distinguish it from the instruction `loop`)? This may even introduce later unwanted bugs, use the colon rather with every label definition. The `510 -( $ - $$ ) db` is also hard to read for somebody aware of typographical rules... `510 - ($ - $$) db` is more proper style.  BTW, if you don't even know the `0x` denotes hexadecimal formatting of value, you should start first with some x86 assembly tutorials, before doing OS.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052492/times-510-db-0-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space after between the `0` and the `x` on line 6.

```
loop :              

    jmp loop        

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0              
dw 0xaa55
```

`0x` indicates a hexadecimal number, and so it cannot be split up with spaces.